# How to add n number of nodes in an xml file?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a xml file in which I need to find the number of nodes and to replace it with n number of same nodes.

This is my input xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VOSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<DbType>Sql</DbType>
<!--<DbType>Oracle</DbType>-->
  <PcNames>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">\\localhost</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">\\localhost</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">\\localhost</anyType>
  </PcNames> 
</VOSettings>
```

The expected output of the xml file should have n number of data inside the PcNames node.
Currently it have 3 values inside PcNames, **my output file should have n number of those values.**
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You dont wanna use java?

Comment: Nope, I have written my complete code in Powershell and now I am stuck in this part.

Comment: If there are multiple child nodes with different values - do you want to copy the first one? Which ones do you want to remove if it's more than `n`? Remove from the bottom? From the top?

Comment: The Node name is fix 'PcNames' and the value (<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">\\localhost</anyType>) as well. So it doesn't matter if we are removing from bottom or top. Its just I need it n times under the node 'PcNames'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume your XML node structure remains the same as your example and **n** represents the total number of nodes you want to have (7 in this code example), you can do the following:

```
$n = 10
$xml = [xml](Get-Content x.xml)

if ($xml.SelectNodes("//PcNames/anyType[text() = '\\localhost']").count) {
    $nodesToCopy = $xml.SelectNodes("//PcNames/anyType[text() = '\\localhost']")
    $NumberOfCopies = $n - $nodesToCopy.count
    $i = $nodesToCopy.Count - 1
} else {
    $nodeTemplate = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VOSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<PcNames>
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">\\localhost</anyType>
</PcNames> 
</VOSettings>
'@
    $nodesToCopy = $nodeTemplate.SelectNodes("//PcNames/anyType[text() = '\\localhost']")
    $nodesTocopy = ,$xml.ImportNode($nodesToCopy[0],$true)
    $NumberOfCopies = $n
    $i = 1
}

$nodeParent = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//PcNames")


while ($NumberOfCopies -lt 0) {
    [void]$nodeParent.RemoveChild($nodesToCopy[$i--])
    $NumberOfCopies++
}

while ($NumberOfCopies -gt 0) {
    $nodeClone = $nodesToCopy[0].CloneNode($true)
    [void]$nodeParent.AppendChild($nodeClone)
    $NumberOfCopies--
}

$xml.Save('c:\temp\new.xml')
```

**Explanation:**

`x.xml` is your original XML file. All nodes called `anyType` that are children of `PcNames` and contain text `\\localhost` are selected and that count is established. `$n` represents **n** number of desired nodes. Whenever **n** is greater than the node count, it will append a clone of one of the nodes to the end of the `PcNames` node. Whenever **n** is less than the node count, it will remove an `anyType` node starting from the top. The number of appends or removals is based on the difference between **n** and the number of `anyType` nodes.

The `if` statement handles the situation of when your target node to copy already exists in your XML document. The `else` statement contains `$nodeTemplate`, which is the XML text for the new node you want to insert. The `else` case is when you don't already have that node in your XML document.

`new.xml` is the newly updated XML output.

Comment: just in case lets say we don't have any value under the node PcNames and I wand to "<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">\\localhost</anyType>" n nuo. of times. What can we do ?

Comment: I've added code to handle the 0 node situation. It is within the `else` statement. You can edit that however you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your question hope this will help.

```
$azVMInventoryList=@() #add n number of element/node in this list
$file=Get-Content -Path "C:\path of the file" 
$lineNumber=($file | Measure-Object).Count
$finalList=@()
$i=0

    for($j=0;$j -lt $lineNumber;$J++){
        if($file[$j] -ne "<PcNames>"){
            $finalList=$finalList+$file[$j]
        }
        if($file[$j] -eq "<PcNames>"){
            $finalList=$finalList+$file[$j]
            $i=$j
            break
        }
    }
    $finalList=$finalList+$azVMInventoryList
    for($k=$i+1;$k -le $lineNumber;$k++){
        if($file[$k] -match "</PcNames>"){
            for($l=$k;$l -le $lineNumber;$l++){
                $finalList=$finalList+$file[$l]
            }
            break
        }
    }
$finalList | Set-Content -Path "C:\path of the file"
```

PS: Ignore the variable naming and you might need few editing according to your need.

Comment: Your answer looks good, but it is removing all the ending tags. For example here it is removing everything below from </PcNames> until end..

Comment: I found the bug in your code, we need to replace 
`$file[$k] -eq "</PcNames>" 
 with
`$file[$k] -match "</PcNames>"

Comment: Thanks @Kaushik for the change. As i mentioned that you might have to do some editing. I will edit the answer.